# How to run pyglet at more than 60fps?

Tags: python, pyglet

I've been trying to make an environment and want to run it as fast as possible (1000+ FPS if possible). I tried experimenting with pyglet, and it seems as though I cannot go beyond 60fps.

I used the following setting to call my update function

```
pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(update, 1.0/120.0)
```

The environment currently has just 1 sprite, and there is no expensive computation that is happening. Running just the update method for 1000 iterations takes 2ms.

It seems to work okay if I reduce the FPS, but always gets capped at 60FPS. Is there any way around this?

Comment: "By default pyglet window buffer swaps are synchronised to the display refresh rate, so you may want to disable vsync."

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Just tried that, and it doesn't seem to change anything. Used window.set_vsync(False).

Answer (score 2):

**From *Migrating from pyglet 1.5*:**

> Application Event Loop
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> In previous releases, the Window was redrawn (and the `Window.on_draw()` event
> dispatched) whenever any scheduled function was called, or event dispatched.
> This often lead to unpredictability and potentially unstable frame rates. In
> pyglet 2.0, a new `interval` argument has been added to `pyglet.app.run`.
> Windows will now always be redrawn at this interval. It defaults to 60fps > (1/60),
> but can be set as desired:

```
@mywindow.event
def on_draw():
    # always called at 120fps

pyglet.app.run(interval=1/120)
```

**Other things to keep in mind:**

https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/programming_guide/time.html

**Periodic Events**

You can schedule updates on an interval.  This is for ideal for animation, physics simulation, and game state updates.

```
pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(update, 1 / 60.0)
```

Or, if you want to call the function as frequently as possible:

```
pyglet.clock.schedule(benchmark)
```

**Vsync**

Pyglet window buffer swaps are synchronized to the display refresh rate, so you may want to disable vsync.  This can specified at window creation time or set with `window.set_vsync(False)`